# How do I integrate FAST Search with MOSS 2007?

Tags: fast-search, 2007

We have two servers:

- Server1: MOSS 2007 content with ESP web parts
- Server2: SP 2010 acting as query server

We need to crawl the Server1 content from Server2, and installed ESP web parts on Server1 need to refer to Server2 as the query server. So user queries from MOSS 2007 go to the SP2010 box (where content is crawled) and return the result on the MOSS 2007 server.

Please advise?

Answer (score 1):

Your ESP webparts aren't going to help you.

What you're asking for is to use SP2010 (FAST 2010?) as your search index & moss as the front-end. The ESP webparts WILL NOT support that requirement as they're built for FAST ESP, a completely different product.

What you need to do is write your own webparts to talk to the SharePoint Query SA. Frankly, you're better off deploying an SP2010 front-end to support the search aspects of your environment/application.

Answer (score 0):

I have integrated SP 2010 with FAST ESP 5.3.3 - see my blog

http://blog.njpenterprises.com/archive/2010/05/23/getting-fast-esp-5-3-3-working-with-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Regards

Nigel